# Increase line height of an inline list

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap for this. I have a fixed width div, that contains an inline `<ul>`. The `<li>`, when exceed the max width, go to the next line. How do I increase the line height (spacing between `<li>` below and `<li>` above) in this case?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out myself. It seems to be just the good old line-height property

Comment: its better to use padding

Comment: Hi Laurens... Just for my knowledge, can you please explain why padding is better? Also padding will be applied on which element? UL or LI?

Answer (score 0):

with padding property also you could increase the width of `LI`